# How to deal with "Undefined index: "

Tags: php

```
if(!isset($aProdcut[$eachYear][$store][$base])){
  $aProdcut[$eachYear][$store][$base] = 0;
}
$aProduct[$eachYear][$store][$base] += $row['total_price'];
```

Undefined index: MARC.  MARC is from $base.

Who can give me some hints?

Comment: Is the issue actually that you're using different spellings of what I assume is meant to be the same variable?

Comment: ^  `$aProdcut` should probably be `$aProduct`.

Comment: You guys have good eyes!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo there $aProdcut vs $aProduct

Comment: This question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) since it's just a simple typo. You can [flag](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) the question for closure. Answering such questions won't help any SO visitors in the future.

Answer (score -1):

The code should not result in undefined index if you have an `$aProduct` variable, which is an `array` and has an index value of `$eachYear`, which is, in turn another array, which has an index value of `$store`, since, in that case

```
isset($aProdcut[$eachYear][$store])
```

is `true`. If that is `true` and it does not have a `$base` index value, then it is created and initialized with 0. Later, when you use it, it will surely exist. So, the issue is probably that `$aProduct[$eachYear]` does not exist or `$aProduct[$eachYear][$store]` is not set. Make sure that everything exists, not just the innermost index and then the problem will be probably fixed. If the problem still persists, then you should check whether some other things are causing it, like multi-threading.

Comment: `$aProduct` !== `$aProdcut` the question should be closed as a typo

Comment: You guys have good eyes!!!